# TYPO3 shows blank page www

Tags: typo3, no-www, typo3-10.x

I just uploaded TYPO3 (10.4.12) from my local to a server and its only reachable when not using www.
Without it the page loads fine, but when using www. it just shows a blank page. It uses the standard htaccess without any modification. Server Host says its TYPO3 settings. But I can't find this anywhere? How can I make it accessible with www.?

Answer (score 0):

blank screen in an production setting means you have an error. look into the server log or switch temporarily to develop mode to identify the error.

I assume a wrong redirect in the domain configuration.